# jumping to #anchor in frameset frame

Tags: javascript, anchor, frameset

I've got 3 frames in a frameset, and after one frame has reloaded I want to jump one of the other frames down to a particular anchor.

Does anyone know how to do that?

I've currently got this javascript but it doesn't seem to work (LEFT_FRAME_ID has already been set):

parent.frames[parent.LEFT_FRAME_ID].hash="#100";

Thanks!

Comment: i think you just need to remove the `#`

Comment: http://www.html-kit.com/forums/archive/web-design/html/jumping-to-anchors-in-other-frames-161/

Comment: tried and tested - and quite well explained too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try `parent.frames[LEFT_FRAME_ID].location = "#100";`.

Alternatively, while it is more complicated and risks triggering a reload, you could rewrite the `location` of the other frame (scan the string for `#`, then replace the remainder).